# start apache & mysql from desktop script in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, apache, bash, ubuntu

on lubuntu 14.04 (desktop) i have installed apache web server and mysql server and, because of low ram (only 1024mb), i decided to remove them from startup (with `sudo update-rc.d -f apache2 remove` and by editing the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file ).

now, every time i want to do some development i have to `sudo service apache2 start` and `sudo service mysql start` in a terminal. wich is fine.

my question is: could those commands be executed from a .sh file? a file that i can double-click it from my desktop?
so far i got

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo service apache2 start
sudo service mysql start
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with scripts which you mentioned.

Apache:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo service apache2 start
```

Mysql

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo service mysql start
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to help, but it's not quite useful :) i did create a .sh file on my desktop, `chmod +x` it so it can execute, put the start apache command in it and when i doubleclick it, it prompts a dialog with "execute" / "execute in terminal" / "open" / "cancel". chosing execute/execute in termnal doesn't start the apache service